# How to use multiple arguments in mutate_all for any function?

Tags: r, dplyr

My data is below

```
grp <- paste('group', sample(1:3, 100, replace = T))
x <- rnorm(100, 100)
y <- rnorm(100, 10)
df <- data.frame(grp = grp, x =x , y =y , stringsAsFactors = F)
lag_size <- c(10, 4, 9)
```

Now when I try to use

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate_all(lag, n = lag_size) %>% arrange(grp)
```

it gives an error

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Expecting a single value:
```

whereas this works fine

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% mutate_all(lag, n = 10) %>% arrange(grp)
```

Comment: You can only have  a single `n` here with `lag`

Comment: [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750761/adding-multiple-lag-variables-using-dplyr-and-for-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to do the `lag` based on the 'grp' i.e. to `lag` the corresponding 'grp' with the value specified in 'lag_size'

```
library(tidyverse)
res <- map2(split(df[2:3], df$grp) , lag_size, ~.x %>% 
                 mutate_all(lag, n = .y)) %>%
                 bind_rows(., .id = 'grp')
```

We can check the `lag` in 'grp' by the position of the first non-NA element

```
res %>% 
      group_by(grp) %>% 
      summarise(n = which(!is.na(x))[1]-1)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     grp     n
#    <chr> <dbl>
#1 group 1    10
#2 group 2     4
#3 group 3     9
```

Comment: It shifts all the columns by all lag values whereas I want to shift different groups by different lags defined in lag_size

Comment: @asad.taj  You have only 3 columns and one of which is 'grp' while the `lag_size` have 3 elements.  i am confused

Comment: sorry about the confusion, number of columns can be more than 2, also `grp` and `lag_size` will always have 1:1 mapping as I want to shift all the columns of dataframe by group as per values in `lag_size`, so each group will be shifted by as per value in `lag_size`

Comment: @asad.taj  I guess I got it.  Please check the update

Comment: comma is missing in your answer `df[,2:3]` stackoverflow is not allowing me to edit as it is just one character

Comment: @asad.taj  You don't need the comma as by default it will select the columns 2 and 3 (if it is a data.frame)