# Simulating an AR(2) Process in R

Tags: r, statistics, autoregressive-models

I need to simulate an AR(2) process `Y[t]=1/20+(Sqrt(3)/2)Y[t-1]-(1/4)Y[t-2]+e[t]`

e[t]~(0,0.02^2)

Simulation has to be over 30 years where the model is measured in quarters.

I've tried with `x <- arima.sim(model = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), ar = c(a1, a2)), n = 120, n.start = 100, sd = 0.02)`

Using the above, R says the model isn't stationary.

Where a1 and a2 are equal to phi 1 and phi 2 in the model, but I can't figure out how to add Phi 0, or how to set values for y0=0.1 and y-1 = 0.12 which is required.

I've also tried the following

```
set.seed(9029) # set a seed to fix the simulated numbers

nsim = 1      # no. of simulations
burn = 100    # burn-in periods
n = 220       # sample length + burn-in periods --> sample length = 4quarters*30yrs
tp=(burn+1):n # time points to be sampled
sigerr = 0.02    # error s.d.
a1 = (sqrt(3)/2)      # AR(2) coefficient
a2 = 0.25     # AR(2) coefficient = 1/4
a0 = 1/20     # Phi 0 

# create data series and error series
y = array(0,c(n,nsim))                          # data series
err = array(rnorm(n*nsim,0,sigerr),c(n,nsim))       # iid errors

# simulate y from an AR(2) process
for (k in 1:nsim) {
  for (i in 2:n) {
    y[i,k] = a0 + a1*y[i-1,k] + a2*y[i-2,k] + err[i,k]
  }
}
```

But keep getting replacement has length zero as an error, and also I still can't find out how to add values for y0 and y-1 equal to 0.1 and 0.12 respectively. Please help I can't seem to find a fix. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is a simple fix, you need to run i from 3 until n. If you want to set values for y_0 or y_1, you need to set the first value in y to y_0 and the second to y_1. And your process is exploding, because you add y[i-2,k], while your formula states you should substract it.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44750761/adding-multiple-lag-variables-using-dplyr-and-for-loops) answer your question?  Note that you don't define `phi1` and `phi2` in your question and your definition of the error term has a typo.  From your code, it should be e[t]~N(0,0.02^2).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, in reply to RBeginner's comment, by running i from 3 until n do you mean for `(i in 3:n) {` where the 3 replaces the 2 in the original code, I also don't quite understand what you mean by setting first and second values in y to y_0 and y_1. 

In response to Limey, the phi 0, phi 1 and phi 2 are the coefficients on the y's, being 1/20, sqrt(3)/2 and -1/4 respectively, and yes sorry forgot the N, but it was normally distributed in the code right?

Comment: I think what @RBeginner meant is that you should set your `x` as `c(y0, y-1, arima.sim(model = list(order = c(2, 0, 0), ar = c(a1, a2)), n = 120, n.start = 100, sd = 0.02))`. Then running it from `3` until `n` will work since you'll have values for the two previous terms needed to estimate the observation at time `i`. Hope it helps!